# How animate multiple elements (matshow and line) at the same time with matplotlib?

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

I'm trying to figure out how to animate multiple elements on a single axis with matplotlib. I can do it with a single elements (either a line or an image from `matshow`) by following: https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2012/08/18/matplotlib-animation-tutorial/ but extending it to 2 elements doesn't seem to be working.

I've seen a few other similar stackoverflow questions, but I seem to be getting a different problem.

Here's the code I tried:

```
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = plt.axes(xlim=[-0.5, np.shape(first_cadence)[0]-0.5], ylim=[-0.5, np.shape(first_cadence)[1]+0.5])

    im = ax.matshow(first_cadence, animated=True)
    line_pos = ax.plot(x[0], y[0], '*')

    def initiate():
        im.set_array(f[0,'FLUX'])
        line_pos.set_data([], [])
        return (im, line_pos)

    def update(i):
        im.set_array(f[i,'FLUX'])
        line_pos.set_data([x[i]], [y[i]])
        return (im, line_pos)

    ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update, range(0, len(f)), init_func=initiate, interval=50, blit=True)

    plt.show()
```

I get a long error statement finishing with:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'set_data'
```

I can post the whole thing if required. For further information, `x` and `y` are just 1D arrays, so I'm plotting a single point in each frame, not a line. I.e: `x = [1.21, 1.20, 1.19, 1.23, ...]`

So I don't know what is going wrong. My guess is that it's something with how I'm returning the elements with the initiate and update functions. I thought since you're supposed to return a tuple with the single element version (i.e `return line,`) then the simple way to extend that to multiple elements would be with a tuple containing all the elements. But that was just a guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that in that tutorial, when they set `line`, there is a comma which you have omitted when you set `line_pos`.

Compare:

```
line, = ax.plot([], [], lw=2)
```

with:

```
line_pos = ax.plot(x[0], y[0], '*')
```

---

This is the source of your error. When you call `ax.plot`, it returns a list of all the `Line2D` objects created.

Note: It returns a list because `.plot` can produce more than one line at once, e.g. `ax.plot(x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3)` will produce three `line2D` objects.

In your case, you only have one line being created, so you can just add a comma after `line_pos` to unpack that one-item list, and leave you just with the `Line2D` object that you need.

i.e. you should change

```
line_pos = ax.plot(x[0], y[0], '*')
```

to

```
line_pos, = ax.plot(x[0], y[0], '*')
```